# How does a function become "incomplete"?

Tags: functions

There are several functions with *incomplete* prefix such as incomplete gamma functions (vs. gamma function), incomplete beta functions (vs. beta functions), or incomplete Bessel functions (vs. Bessel functions).

It seems that the "incomplete" functions are the generalized versions of their own "normal" counterparts by introducing new parameters. However, I do not find any formal definition when and how we can call a new function *incomplete*.

Anyone knows the definition?

Comment: The examples you cite use the word "incomplete" in the sense that these are defined as integrals over some proper subset of the domain of integration of the "complete" function.  Thus, "completeness" in this context refers to the extent of the domain of integration.

Comment: The gamma function is defined as a certain definite integral.  The incomplete gamma function  is the same indefinite integral.  I think this terminology was first used with elliptic integrals $F, \Pi, K$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind

Comment: Thank guys, your comments are informative.